# Insert multiple elements between two similar element of same list

Tags: c#, linq

I want add multiple elements between two elements of same list. Below is the code snippet.

```
List<string> s = {'A','B','B','C','D','E','E' }
```

If current and next character is same  in the list so that it should enter 4 elements of '-' character and list should be like

```
List<string> s = {'A','B','-','-','-','-','B','C','D','E','-','-','-','-','E' }
```

I am able to achieve the output with multiple for loop. I want to avoid loops and try to achieve it through some linq or lambda expressions.

Comment: Sounds like a home task :)

Comment: This case is not valid. If such case arises then it will remove one of the entry and still have A, - , - , - , - , A

Comment: You mentioned "multiple for loop", i think it can be done with one for loop, and whats wrong with that? why should you try to accomplish it with LINQ?

Comment: Not valid syntax for List<string>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of dashes is fixed, you can put them in manually, like this:

```
var res = s.SelectMany((v, i) =>
    i > 0 && s[i - 1] == v ? new[] {"-", "-", "-", "-", v} : new[] { v }
).ToList();
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/MF2m2L)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This will solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, just with the idea, is iterate through the list with some loop and test current item with the last item. If both are equals, you can use the `Insert(int index, T item)` method:

```
List<string> s = {'A','B','B','C','D','E','E' }
List<string> s2insert = {'-','-','-','-'}

//iterate the list...
//if current item and last item are same, do:
s.Insert(current_position, s2insert);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A single loop

```
foreach (char c in FillIn(new List<char> { 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E' }))
    Debug.WriteLine(c);


static IEnumerable<char> FillIn(IEnumerable<char> input)
{
    char? cLast = null;
    char filler = '-';
    foreach(char c in input)
    { 
        if (cLast == c)
        {
            yield return filler;
            yield return filler;
            yield return filler;
            yield return filler;
        }
        cLast = c;
        yield return c;
    }
}
```